# Windows 10 making system sounds while copying or moving files to/from Android device(MTP)

Tags: windows-10

The sound is made after copying/moving each and ever file. It's infuriating me.

The sound is Windows_Foreground.wav and the copying pops in front after every single file transfer or notifies/blinks with an orange glow.

Is it somehow related to the ADB drivers or something else?

Comment: Got to Control Panel (icon view)>Sound>Sounds Tab, go through the program events and find the offending event that has the foreground.wav sound and set it to not have any sound, hit apply.

Comment: This seems to be connected to battery low status.

Answer (score 0):

if you transfering to phone, and this problem occurs in a while, i mean other files are copying normally and some specific file or folder have this issue, then rename the file or folder, this problem occurs because of long name or unsupported character on file or folder name, if you are copying folder then rename files inside it,,, it works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).